# How to prevent URL manipulation in Express routing?

Tags: node.js, express

Let's suppose we have set the following routing in Express:

`/games/:gameId/events/:id`

Then such a request could be send:

`curl http://api.mysite.com/games/data/events/1`

However, if a malicious user sends a request like this:

`http://api.mysite.com/games/game1/events/..%2f..%2f..%2fgames`

and there is a subsequent URL call, the url for it will look like:

`http://api.mysite.com/games`

which may retrieve the whole games collection.

**Right now our protection is**: validate the params explicitly - for example this event Id should consist from numbers and characters, but we want to improve this and to set a protection from this kind of exploit only once in our app.

My question is: is there any built-in functionality in Express or some plugin, which protects the routes from such kind of exploit?
Is there a way to escape somehow these `../`?

Comment: `and there is a subsequent URL call` Huh?

Comment: You need authorization.  You should make it impossible for your code to return data that the user should not see, regardless of URLs.

Comment: you should filter with auth, use tokens/cookies to validate the user otherwise it should be forbidden to everyone 403 @Joachim

Comment: What is this "subsequent URL"?  Anyone can send an API call of `http://api.mysite.com/games` at any time so you just need to not only validate incoming parameters, but also make sure that anyone requesting a URL is authorized to access that URL.

Comment: Also `..` in a URL will not cause any issues with Express routing.  It might cause an issue if YOUR code turns parameters directly into file paths or something like that where `..` might have a different meaning.  But, that would be an issue with YOUR code that you would have to protect against.

Comment: @jfriend00 As I said, we are now protecting our code by ourselves and it works fine. I hoped however there would be something more general invented so far.

Comment: periods or escaped slashes are allowed in URLs so there's no generic protection against them being in URLs at all.  Those are perfectly legal URLs.  It is only what YOU do with the path of the URL in express that can cause problems.  `express.static()` has an option to prevent the processing of `../` in paths if you want to use that, but that does not appear to be what you are asking about.  So, it all depends upon what you do with the path and you have to make your own protections for that.